# Angular JS shows blank screen when user idle for long time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

My application is built in MEAN Stack. Application works fine but when a page kept idle for long time its content get blank and blank screen shows.

I also using socket in the application. No idea what goes wrong when user idle for long time.